# how to show multiple images one by one with respect to mouse click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I write a jquery code for one image show with respect to a mouse click and that image replaced with another image in a time delay. Code  attached below

```
 <div>
        <script>
            document.onclick = userClicked;
            function userClicked() {
                var x = event.clientX;
                var y = event.clientY;
                var snowball = document.getElementById("snowballAppear");
                snowball.style.display = '';
                snowball.style.position = 'relative';
                snowball.style.left = x;
                snowball.style.top = y;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById("snowballAppear").setAttribute("src", "d2.png");
                }, 5000);
            }
        </script>
        <img id="snowballAppear" style="display: none;margin-left: -800px;margin-top: -30px;" src="bul.png"/>

    </div>
```

I want to replace this code with multiple images show with respect to continuous mouse click in jquery.

Comment: try to create a fiddler or snippet to explain in an easy way

Comment: No idea what you mean. Is this google translate or your own english? You may want to use google translate it can give a better translation. Also, no need to pay respect to a mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

Having a hard time understanding what you want. How about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  imgs = [
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/asdfes',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/gsedes',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/hrdhrc',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/hrdrbs',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/grrcbr',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/dfgrbrd' /*...more images*/
    ];
  var i = 0;
  
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var x = event.clientX,
      y = event.clientY;
    $('#snowballAppear').css({
      display: '',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: x,
      left: y
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('hi');
      $('#snowballAppear').attr('src', imgs[i]);
      i = i === imgs.length ? 0 : i + 1;
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="snowballAppear" style="display: none;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/adfsfes" />

</div>
```

Comment: Actually i try to develop a new UI with an animation effect. so i used 2 character images. first image showing  code is attached in my question. i want to display the second character when my second mouse click. so please help me. and also i want to hide second character image upto my second mouse click.